If one class contains an object of another, which coupling is it?
For example, I have a class1 and then I make a class2 and use the method of the object of class1 there. If I only pass simple data, is it a 1 level coupling?
I'm not really sure about it, and don't have much experience either, and although I've done some research and that's the conclusion, but I still think I might be wrong about it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
